# 8 Capabilities Unavailable for specific app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

[image]Hi I have an app which is also live,
For the next version I want to implement deep linking for this I have to enable Associated Domains.
I have enabled it at bundle Identifier also created new provisioning profile downloaded and double clicked it.
But still 8 capabilities missing, Associated Domains is one of them.
Please someone help how can I get Associated Domains under capabilities.
Only attached options are there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's because Associated Domains where introduced in iOS9. If your application is targeting older iOS versions, it could be the reason.

Comment: Its available for other apps they also have minimum target  of version 8.0

Comment: In xCode Select Target and then General Tab (next to capabilities tab). Select the right "Team", also make sure in build settings you have selected correct provisioning profile and capabilities should appear in capabilities tab. Hope this solves the problem for you.

Comment: I've fixed the same issue by updating account info. It said "Password expired".
Try to check Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

Answer (score 4):

For me it was because my developer membership expired. The Capabilities tab show something like `10 capabilities unavailable`. Renewed my membership, restarted Xcode, and they all showed up