# Missing iCloud capability in project

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I am working on a project where i would like to use iCloud capability.
My appleID has been added to Apple Developer Program. However, I cannot find any sign of iCloud or CloudKit capabilities in xCode. There are only few basic ones. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Maybe it has something to do with adding it to existing project?

[general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfSg8.png)

[capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GUdP.png)

EDIT2: I have been added as a user to a university group. I am not sure but maybe I am using wrong credentials. On my individual page in ADP i have no membership but when i look through my university profile i can see myself as a user of program.
The issue is the same. However i believe my problem is the account i'm using. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Look at the Capabilities tab of your project.

Comment: That's what i am looking at. There are only few basic ones, no CloudKit or iCloud.

Comment: Post a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [8 Capabilities Unavailable for specific app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968784/8-capabilities-unavailable-for-specific-app)

Comment: The issue is the same. However i am having troubles (possibly) with the account i am using. I can't figure it out.

Comment: I've fixed the same issue by updating account info. It said "Password expired".
Try to check Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an existing project after signing up for the Apple Developer Program.

Closing the existing project, and then creating a new random project solved the problem for some reasons.  The advance capabilities now appeared for both the existing and the random projects!